# How to determine the classloader during class initialization?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, classloader, eclipse-jdt

I am using the Eclipse debugger and set a breakpoint in a class initializer (e.g. static field initialization).

Is there a way to determine/inspect the classloader which is used to load the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be...

```
ClassA.class.getClassLoader();
```

Comment: Not in a static initializer. But `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()` works.

Comment: @AljoshaBre getClass() is an Object instance method. It does not work in static contexts, and much less in class initizializers.

Comment: @Stephan Good guess, but this also does not work because the class is not loaded yet

Comment: @MRalwasser I tried it using a very simple test class within an `static {..}` block, there it works, do you get an exception or just `null`?

Comment: @MRalwasser The class is already loaded when static{} runs (it's just not initialized yet), so MyClass.class.getClassLoader() should work.

Comment: @Stephan, you're right, it worked. Thank you! Unfortunately you didn't post that as an answer so I cannot award it. I'll accept the answer here, even the author had modified it from a wrong answer to your (correct) one.